# Updating Hebrew text in SQL Server database end up with "???"

Tags: c#, sql, database, input, hebrew

I'm writing a C# program to enter data into SQL Server 2008 database.

I use the following function to enter info into database

```
public bool AddSupplier(string name, string contactPerson, string telephone, string fax, string type, string payment, string comments)
{
        _cmd.CommandText =
            "INSERT INTO suppliers (name,contactPerson,telephone,fax,type,payment,active,comments) VALUES (@name,@contactPerson,@telephone,@fax,@type,@payment,@active,@comments);";
        _cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
        _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactPerson", contactPerson);
        _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", telephone);
        _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", fax);
        _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
        _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment", payment);
        _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", 1);
        _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", comments);
        _con.Open(); 
        _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        _con.Close();
        return true; 
    }
```

This works fine, I can add info in Hebrew and it shows up in the database.

When I try to edit it using this function

```
public bool EditSupplier(int supplierId,string name, string contactPerson, string telephone, string fax, string type, string payment, string comments)
{
        _cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE suppliers SET name='" + name + "' ,contactPerson='" + contactPerson + "',telephone='" + telephone +
                           "',fax='" + fax + "',type='" + type + "',payment='" + payment + "',comments='" + comments +
                           "' WHERE supplierId =" + supplierId + ";";
        _con.Open(); 
        _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _con.Close();
        return true; 
}
```

I end up with `???` instead of the Hebrew input

Comment: you have to encode the string before passing it along with the proper encoding for hebrew characters...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use parameterized SQL for the update command as well as the insert command. You should be doing that *anyway* in order to prevent SQL Injection attacks - the fact that it plays better with non-ASCII characters is a bonus.

(IIRC, you can use a literal from `N'...'` if you *really* must, but I'd strongly advise you not to.)

Additionally, it would be better to create a new connection and command each time you want to use the database, and using a `using` statement to dispose of it at the right time. Don't worry about the efficiency side - the built-in connection pool will handle that.

Comment: so just make it work in the same way i use the insert with the values?

Comment: @Iakovl: Yes, exactly - admittedly I'd use `cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name` instead of using `AddWithValue`, but that's a slightly different matter. Note the last paragraph of my answer, too.

Comment: the N'...' helped in another function with search function, that for that. can you explain the 2nd paragraph or refer to info

Comment: @Iakovl: I'd rather not, because that suggests that you're still coding values into SQL. Use parameterized SQL *everywhere*.

Comment: I do not agree with the second recommendation - to create new connection for each command. For desktop applications connected over LAN with server, it is not necessary and keeping open connection is the better way.

Comment: @i486: It's much easier to write *correct* code with a separate logical connection each time, and the connection pool takes care of mapping that to a "real" connection efficiently. It's not like the network connection will actually be broken. What do you believe the benefit of keeping a `SqlConnection` open in your own code is? How do you then ensure you never have two operations on the same connection at the same time? This is precisely what the connection pool is designed for, to allow your code to be simpler whilst retaining performance.

Comment: With open connections you know how many clients are connected (logically - until logoff/disconnect). Connection pool may help but without disconnection the work is faster - even with very small %. I am not sure how simple may be the code - any attempt to make limitation of simultaneous logins (for example) will make the code much more complex. For example, why SQL Management Studio keeps open connection and does not disconnect after each query? What will be the usage of system stored proc `sp_who`/`sp_who2` if everybody reopens connections? Disconnections are useful for web interface.

Comment: @i486: Have you benchmarked your code to *prove* that leaving a `SqlConnection` open is faster? And no, using simultaneous *independent* connections is very simple. It means that if you start an operation in one thread but need to cancel the operation, you don't need to worry, etc. I've no idea what you mean about "disconnections are useful for web interface" but really, creating a new `SqlConnection` on each operation is the standard recommended approach for .NET, whatever kind of client you're using. Closing that won't *actually* disconnect as far as the server is concerned, due to the pool.